# Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I've read a lot of answers about this error and I don't find the solution for mine maybe the class object isn't the same

My error is :

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT

So, I just trying to get an Object from JSON like this :

```
JsonObject mS1SystemStatusJsonObject = parameterEntries.getValue().getAsJsonObject();

MS1SystemStatusResponse mS1SystemStatusResponse = gson.fromJson(mS1SystemStatusJsonObject, MS1SystemStatusResponse.class);
```

my JsonObject is :

```
{
 "WARNING_CONDITION_LIST":
  {
   "warningConditionList": {"warningCondition":"BLACK_POSTAL_INK_WF_COND"}
   },
 "DISABLING_CONDITION_LIST": {"disablingConditionList":""},
 "CurrentErrorList":"",
 "LockState":"lockspend",
"SystemReadyState":true
}
```

My differents POJO (i don't put get and set for short the code) :

```
public class MS1SystemStatusResponse{

@SerializedName("LockState")
String lockState;

@SerializedName("SystemReadyState")
Boolean systemReadyState;

@SerializedName("WARNING_CONDITION_LIST")
WARNING_CONDITION_LIST warningConditionListMy;

@SerializedName("DISABLING_CONDITION_LIST")
DISABLING_CONDITION_LIST disablingConditionListMy;

@JsonAdapter(EmptyStringAsNullTypeAdapter.class)    
@SerializedName("CurrentErrorList")
CurrentErrorList currentErrorList;


public class WARNING_CONDITION_LIST {

@SerializedName(value = "warningConditionList")
@JsonAdapter(EmptyStringAsNullTypeAdapter.class)
WarningConditionList warningConditionList;


public class DISABLING_CONDITION_LIST {

@SerializedName(value = "disablingConditionList")
@JsonAdapter(EmptyStringAsNullTypeAdapter.class)
DisablingConditionList disablingConditionList;

public class CurrentErrorList {

@SerializedName(value = "Error")
private Error error;


public class WARNING_CONDITION_LIST {

@SerializedName(value = "warningConditionList")
@JsonAdapter(EmptyStringAsNullTypeAdapter.class)
WarningConditionList warningConditionList;


public class WarningConditionList {

@SerializedName(value = "warningCondition")
String warningCondition;
```

Here is the full stack trace and another class that i've forgot to add before :

Stacktrace :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader.nextString(JsonTreeReader.java:154)
    com.pb.marqueo.connect.plus.api.common.model.response.EmptyStringAsNullTypeAdapter.read(EmptyStringAsNullTypeAdapter.java:24)
    com.pb.marqueo.connect.plus.api.common.model.response.EmptyStringAsNullTypeAdapter.read(EmptyStringAsNullTypeAdapter.java:10)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217)
    com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:861)
    com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:926)
    com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:899)
    com.pb.marqueo.connect.plus.api.core.service.impl.ConnectPlusServicesImpl.getMS1SystemStatus(ConnectPlusServicesImpl.java:410)
    com.pb.marqueo.connect.plus.api.core.facade.impl.ConnectPlusBusinessServicesImpl.startProduction(ConnectPlusBusinessServicesImpl.java:1236)
    com.pb.marqueo.connect.plus.rest.services.impl.ConnectPlusControllerImpl.startProd(ConnectPlusControllerImpl.java:280)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.pb.marqueo.common.filter.OriginFilter.doFilter(OriginFilter.java:70)
```

Class Adapter :

```
public class EmptyStringAsNullTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, String value) throws IOException {
        out.value(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
        }

        String result = in.nextString();
        if ("".equals(result)) {
            return null;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I turn around since 1 week :(

Comment: what does mS1SystemStatusJsonObject  print?

Comment: Can you try to replace `"SystemReadyState":true` with `"SystemReadyState":"true"` ?

Comment: No, i cant replace this, it affect a lot things in program, i dont have the error when the WARNING_CONDITION_LIST is empty

Comment: When asking about an exception, **always** post the complete exception stack trace of the exception.

Comment: You're using an adapter named EmptyStringAsNullTypeAdapter on properties that are not Strings. That's probably the reason: it expects a string, but gets an object. The stack trace would probably confirm that.

Comment: i've add the full stacktrace

Comment: @JBNizet i've added the full stack trace and the Adapter

Comment: That confirms what I said. The exception is thrown by the adapter, which tries to read a string. And since it's applied to fields of type CurrentErrorList, WarningConditionList and DisablingConditionList, none of them being strings, you get the exception. Remove this annotation, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191996/discussion-between-stephanie-joyce-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: No, I don't chat, sorry. If you have other comments, make them here.

Comment: When i remove the annotation, i got the error in other sense : 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING 
com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader.expect(JsonTreeReader.java:139) 
com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader.beginObject(JsonTreeReader.java:70) 
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:189) 
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)

Comment: That's because the disablingConditionList field in DISABLING_CONDITION_LIST is of type DisablingConditionList in your Java model, but is a String in the JSON.

Comment: Because in this case it's empty, it can be a list as warningConditionList

Comment: Then use null instead of an empty string in your JSON. BTW, whet you're calling a "list", is not a list at all. It's an object.

Comment: Can you show is how you're creating the `gson` instance?

Comment: @Fred Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

Comment: wait... where are you then adding the type adapter?

Comment: @Fred i dont understand what do u mean ? i've showed where the Adapter has been added

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I didn't realized you had the annotations. Ok, let me check a couple of things and see if I can help.

Comment: ok, so you're trying to deserialize an object - `WarningConditionList` - as a string and this doesn't work. That's what the error tells you. I'm having trouble understanding what's the end goal? Do you want to simply deserialize empty strings as null? Can the json be like `{ "WARNING_CONDITION_LIST": ""}`?

Comment: for WarningConditionList, i want to deserialize it in Null value if it equals " " or get the list object if it's not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so from the conversation in the comments I understood that you want to be able to deserialize both of these cases:

```
{
  "WARNING_CONDITION_LIST": {
      "warningConditionList": {"warningCondition":"BLACK_POSTAL_INK_WF_COND"}
  },
  ...
}
```

and

```
{
  "WARNING_CONDITION_LIST": ""
  ...
}
```

In the first scenario, you want the object and in the 2nd scenario, you want `null`.

The first thing I noticed is that you have the `@JsonAdapter` annotation in the wrong place. It should actually be in the `WARNING_CONDITION_LIST` field. Something like this:

```
public class MS1SystemStatusResponse {
  // ...
  @SerializedName("WARNING_CONDITION_LIST")
  @JsonAdapter(EmptyStringAsNullTypeAdapter.class)
  WARNING_CONDITION_LIST warningConditionListMy;
  // ...
}
```

However, this alone will not solve your problem. The problem is within the `EmptyStringAsNullTypeAdapter`. It expects the field to just be a string and doesn't handle the case when it can be an object. For this, we can write the following adapter:

```
public class EmptyStringAsEmptyWarningConditionlTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<WARNING_CONDITION_LIST> {

  @Override
  public void write(JsonWriter out, WARNING_CONDITION_LIST value) throws IOException {
    out.beginObject();
    out.name("warningConditionList");
    out.value(value.warningConditionList.warningCondition);
    out.endObject();
  }

  @Override
  public WARNING_CONDITION_LIST read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    WARNING_CONDITION_LIST result = new WARNING_CONDITION_LIST();
    result.warningConditionList =  new WarningConditionList();
    result.warningConditionList.warningCondition = "";

    if (in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
        in.beginObject();
        in.nextName();
        in.beginObject();
        in.nextName();
        result.warningConditionList.warningCondition = in.nextString();
        in.endObject();
        in.endObject();
    } else {
        in.nextString();
        return null;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Essentially it will check if you have a string or an object and return `null` or the object respectively.

This works only for these 2 cases that I've shown you with the json and should be enough to help you out figuring the rest.

You'll probably face a similar issue with the `CurrentErrorList`.

Comment: Thank's, i'll try this, i'll create 2 others adapter similar to this and i see if it works

Comment: For this input : 

{"WARNING_CONDITION_LIST":{"warningConditionList":""},"DISABLING_CONDITION_LIST":{"disablingConditionList":""},"CurrentErrorList":"","LockState":"lockspend","SystemReadyState":true}

I've got an error : in.nextName() : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Comment: yes, I explained in my answer that this only works for the 2 jsons I have in the answer and it won't work for anything else. It's an explanation of how the type adapter can be used. It's not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve, but if you want to make the `warningConditionList` null when it's an empty string, then just move the type adapter one level deep and adapt the code.

Comment: I've update it like this and it works, thank u so much

if (in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
           in.beginObject();
           in.nextName();
           result.getDisablingConditionList().setDisablingCondition(in.nextString());
           in.endObject();
         } else {       
          result.getDisablingConditionList().setDisablingCondition(in.nextString());
         }